# Why is this javascript code to change background color not working?

Tags: javascript, css, html, background-color

I want to change the background color ,when the user clicks the button, to the color he/she selected from the dropdown. Here's the html and javascript code for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Change Color Demo</title>
        <script>
            function changeColor(){
                var selColor = document.getElementById("selColor");
                var color = selColor.value;
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <fieldset>
                <select id="selColor">
                    <option value="FFFFFF">White</option>
                    <option value="FF0000">Red</option>
                    <option value="FFCCFF">Orange</option>
                    <option value="FFFF00">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="00FF00">Green</option>
                    <option value="0000FF">Blue</option>
                    <option value="663366">Indigo</option>
                    <option value="FF00FF">Violet</option>
                </select>

                <input type="button" value="change color" onClick="changeColor()"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it's not working for some reason. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see why you were down-voted. You asked a clear and concise question and provided enough information for us to provide a solution.

Comment: That happens a lot on SO. Apparently the question also has to be challenging for some folks around here or else they just down-vote it.

Comment: More than likely it was a knee-jerk reaction to the fact that you a) Didn't describe what the actual problem was and b) You didn't mention checking for any errors in the console.  While neither is actually *required*, the phrase 'not working' tends to set people off.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher If I knew what the problem was, I would have fixed it. Since I did not know what was going wrong, I had to post it here. My editor(Komodo edit), did not show any warning or error in regards to that "#" that I missed. I would love to know any other way of asking this question here without using the words "not working". Thanks

Comment: @Blasttrash: You could have said:  "The background color doesn't change even after I set it in line <x>."  That would have both described the expected behavior and actual behavior.  I know that it duplicates the title, to a certain degree, but that's OK.  I didn't mention any of this as a criticism of *your* post, but a possible explanation as to motive of the down-voter.  I know that I tend to skip questions where the asker doesn't include enough information.

Comment: No, I totally understand that you did not mention your comment as criticism of your post, I was just trying to gain some advice from an experienced user such as yourselves about asking questions on SO. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS colours using hex to represent RGB must start with a `#` character.

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing '#'. Just a tiny fix:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#"+color;
```

Comment: Thanks. That's also a pretty cool trick to solve this problem. :D